# Get date and time retrieved from database into a datetime input

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to retrieve a `Datetime` value from my database and place it in an `html input` with a `date type` but it doesn't show anything.

```
$resQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reserveringen WHERE id = $ID");
while ($resInfo = mysql_fetch_array($resQuery))
        {
          $dateTime = $resInfo[3];
        }

<?php echo "<input name='dateTime' type='datetime-local' value='$dateTime'"?>
```

Also when I `F12` I get this error: `The specified value "2525-0505-16161616 0606:0505" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS"`.

Comment: That error is telling you exactly what is wrong. `2525-0505-16161616 0606:0505` isn't a valid date time string.

Comment: Iknow it is telling me what is wrong but i do not know how to apply that to the code

Comment: Are you sure you got right column? Value `2525-0505-16161616 0606:0505` is not a date... Do `print_r($resInfo);` and show us the result

Comment: You need to convert the value into something like  `2016-05-26T13:29` (or use another column because that doesn't look like a date-time value at all).

Comment: It is the correct column but how do i convert that value then? I mean it is retrieved from the database as a Date value i wouldnt know what to convert it to

Comment: Try to use sql DATE_FORMAT().

Comment: where is your insert code @WilliamBruijntjes

Comment: Im not inserting anything. I'm trying to retrieve it into the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me guys!

I changed my query to:

`SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(Datum, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') AS Datum_conv  FROM reserveringen WHERE id = $ID`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you was writing data into database you used wrong date format. Look carefully at datetime value:

```
2525-0505-16161616 0606:0505
```

It must be

```
25-05-16 06:05
```

What you did when saving data is using these date format:

```
date('dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii')
```

instead of this

```
date('d-m-Y H:i');
```

Comment: How would I change this?

Comment: Firstly, you should change date format where you save it. then you have to fix all dates values in your database. Probably manually - or just set them to null and then edit programmatically.

Comment: @WilliamBruijntjes If it was being written to an actual date/time datatype in the database, then it should always be `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.... what datatype are you using in your database?

Comment: I am using 'Y-m-d H:i:s' but I am sure it has that format at the saving time. Make sure you has the same format you expect at saving.
"DateTime format" - what  does it mean?
What I am saying is that you shouldn't use format 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii' when you save the data into database. Check out what string is being inserted in your table?

Comment: Im not trying to insert anything tough i'm trying to retrieve it into the Input

Comment: My point is that the mistake happens not when you retrieve the data but when the data is being saved. So, look at the code where the data is being inserted into database and make sure that datetime format is set properly.

Comment: If not you then someone else has inserted this value. Find the place where it happens.

Comment: It is inserted at this point: <input name='dateTime' type='datetime-local' required> then with a php file retrieving the form values and inserting them in the database @Alex